# Канал pipe между двумя консолями

Tags: c++, c

Здравствуйте. Нужно что-то типо клиент сервер. Сама программа аналог утилиты dir. При запуске создает две консоли. Задача клиента передать путь до папки серверу через канал pipe. Сервер обрабатывают саму программу и передает обратно результат её выполнения. Помогите с этим pipe.

Сама программа сервера:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *entry;
  if (argc > 1){
      dir = opendir(argv[1]);
  }
  if (!dir) {
      perror("diropen");
      return 1;
  };

  while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
  {
      printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
  };

  closedir(dir);
  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
};
```

Разобрался, только теперь одна проблема. 
Эта функция которая передает данные клиенту:

```
while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) 
{ 
    if (!WriteFile(hNamedPipe, entry->d_name, strlen(szBuf) + 1, &cbWritten, NULL)); 
}; `
```

Эта принимает:

`if (ReadFile(hNamedPipe, szBuf, 512, &cbRead, NULL));`

Итог то что клиент видит только первую строку которую передал сервер. Потому что он не зациклен, а я не знаю сколько строк придет чтобы через for сделать. А через while не знаю как. Есть что то типо "пока сервер передает, принимай"?

Comment: Для какой ОС пишите?

Comment: Поясните подробнее в чем проблема и какая помощь нужна.

Comment: @Cerbo Не могу разобраться: 1. Как сделать так чтобы при запуске, программа создавала две консоли. 2. Как их связать, т.е нужно на сервере создать канал CreateNamedPipe(buf) и на клиенте ConnectNamedPipe(buf)? И получается открывать его на запись, тогда когда передаю путь до папки. закрывать на запись. открывать на чтение и считывать на сервере, получается так?

Comment: @avp для Windows, на Visual Studio

Comment: Просто передайте какое-нибудь невозможное в винде имя (например, один '\') в качестве индикатора конца.

Comment: Я имею в виду конец цикла `while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) { if (!WriteFile(...` Вам же об этом событии надо сообщить по пайпу.

Comment: Я же и говорю, вместо нормального имени (которые Вы шлете) отправляете *невозможное* (достаточно из одного символа). Читаете такое и понимаете, что все, больше имена посылать не будут.

Comment: @Anrey Пожалуйста, перенесите все свои уточнения из коментариев в вопрос, а перенесенные коментарии удалите. Таковы правила ресурса. Здесь не форум!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилась проблема давно, решил ответить сам на свой вопрос, может пригодится кому нибудь. Пошел по пути который дал @avp. А т.е отправил символ который не может встретиться в папке ("|").
Получилось после всей отправки данных на сервере:

```
if (!WriteFile(hNamedPipe, "|", strlen(szBuf) + 1, &cbWritten, NULL));
```

На клиенте:

```
if (strcmp(szBuf, "|") != 0)
{
    //если не пришел этот символ
}
else
{
    break; //выход из цикла while (чтения данных)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обманите цикл while, указав в его условии true, так как операция чтения канала (pipe) является блокируемой (если входных данных нет, программа не выполняется), с вами не случится зацикливание кода.